# how to share dependecy in programs

Tags: java, maven, module

I work with maven and i create a library. My library use some dependency and i need, when a program that uses my library, use also dependency, which is defined inside my library. Is it possible with maven ?

for example pom A:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    </dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>some.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>${some.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and than when some program use my library as below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sk.bajky.reflection</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    </dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

i need the program use dependency which was specified in pom A.

Comment: _"i need the program use dependency which was specified in pom A."_ Why?

Comment: If you just want to make sure that your library gets the right version of its dependency, use the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to [relocate the classes in the dependency](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html).

Comment: i need to use also plugins from POM A. Is it possible ?

Comment: Wher does `${some.version}` come from? There's neither a [`<parent>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) nor a [`<properties>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) section declared in your _A_ POM.

Comment: in <properties> of current pom

Comment: Shouldn't this be handled by a [BOM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) ?

Comment: _Current pom_? Is this a third one? If I may be honest: your question (including your comments) is a bit unclear. You show a library „_pom A_“ with `<artifactId>library`. You show a "_program_" that has also `<artifactId>library`. Then you introduce a "_current pom_" and you also would like to use inherited plugins, which is a topic different to dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. There are a few options:

1. Declare:

   ```
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>some.group</groupId>
       <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
       <version>${some.version}</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```

   in `sk.bajky.reflection:library` POM, as well.
2. Create a [parent](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) POM that contains:

   ```
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>some.group</groupId>
       <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
       <version>${some.version}</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```

   and add it as `<parent>` to each of your POMs.
3. Create a parent POM that contains [Dependency Management](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Management):

   ```
   <dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>some.group</groupId>
         <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
         <version>${some.version}</version>
       </dependency>
     </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   ```

   add it as `<parent>` to each of your POMs and add also the following to your POMs:

   ```
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>some.group</groupId>
       <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```
4. Create a parent POM that contains Dependency Management and the dependency to be inherited by your POMs:

   ```
   <dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>some.group</groupId>
         <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
         <version>${some.version}</version>
       </dependency>
     </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>some.group</groupId>
       <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```

   and add it as `<parent>` to each of your POMs.